# Rummikub Joker Rule Question

Tags: rummikub, joker

Can you use a rummikub joker tile in an existing run?  Or must a joker always be replaced in order to use it?

Answer (score 1):

While a joker is on the table it retains the number and colour set when it was initially placed.
This means it can be used as part of a players manipulation, as long as the number and colour needed are the same, and all sets are valid at the end of the manipulation.

The joker only needs to be retrieved if it's wildcard abilities are required for placing a set.